# Measurement, Multi-pin voltage visualizer?

Tags: voltage-measurement

Are there better&standard way to debug/inspect multiple pin voltages instead of a multmeter? It is rather inefficient.

Comment: Specify your need a little better. How many points to be inspected? Voltage ranges? Test as in new board testing? Repair? Calibration?

Comment: ATE uses a bed of nails tester to sequential MUX nodes to ADC. a logic probe is portable, cheaper and faster.

Comment: Do you need to know voltages, or just logic? Logic analyzers are quite common, and many oscilloscopes have logic analyzer functionality as an option, with an additional sixteen or so channels of logic inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some bench multimeters have an input multiplexer option which can be used with GPIB to make measurements of many points under computer control (HP/Keysight used to make this stuff).

If it is just logic levels you are interested in then a logic analyser (or if the design is suitable, JTAG) works anf typically can sample quickly enough to give you timing data.

Sometimes you design in BITE to allow sampling of interesting points with something like a built in ADC.

Comment: I've not seen the term BITE before; would it be correct to assume it stands for built-in test equipment?

Comment: @Hearth Yep, sometimes it is also used for functional tests during equipment startup. Some of the OLD HP stuff would even tell you "TEST 07 Failed : PLL Out of range, 20% VCO Board, 40% Loop board, 20% Reference board, 20% other" or similar, which was telling you where the designers figured the fault was most likely to be found (They didn't always get it right, but it was helpful).

Answer (score -1):

Checkout DAQs, they offer multiple channels (depending on the model). You can not only get RMS value of the voltage(or current) but can also get the transient data as well.

Comment: Don't you mean ADC ….Analog to Digital Converter rather then DAC ...Digital to Analog Converter. DAQ means both (as a system typically) in terms of industry advertising.

Comment: DAQs have ADC in them, so yes i mean a device capable of having multiple ADC channels working simultaneously.

Comment: DAQ is an abbreviation meaning a data acquisition system that usually comprises a multiplexer followed by an analog to digital converter.